# Generating date_time_zonespec.csv for boost::date_time from IANA's time zone database?

Tags: boost, timezone, boost-date-time, iana

The time zone database (date_time_zonespec.csv or boost_1_55_0/libs/date_time/data/date_time_zonespec.csv) of boost::date_time library seems [not to be up to date](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/10087). Is there a way to generate it from [latest version of IANA time zone database](https://www.iana.org/time-zones)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be the answer found in [boost::locale reference](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/locale/doc/html/dates_times_timezones.html):

> Why don't you use Boost.DateTime time zone support?
>
> Boost.DateTime's time zone support is broken. Time zones can not be
>   represented with a simple table of rules where daylight saving depend
>   only on certain n'th day of week in month. The daylight savings time
>   may vary by year, political issues and many other things.

Answer (score 1):

There is also the new C++20 date functions, added to the chrono lib. It can use your system's TZ database, at least on Linux/Mac, or you can have the library automatically download the latest TZ to a folder instead. You can try it out here: https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date